# Why does browser reserve this space?

Tags: .net, postback, panel

I have a bit off html  that outputs a grid. It's as simple as this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The inner li's are styled side by side using inline-block. Both are 220px wide, with a left-margin of 20px;

However I apply a first-child filter on the li so the total width will be 460px,
 (220 + 20 + 220).

I would like to restrict the width of the ul's parent by putting a width of 460px on it, but when I do the li's don't have enough room to sit side by side and render beneath each other.

Ar the any techniques that will handle this?

Comment: Remove all margins and paddings before applying your style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was an inline-block issue.

The way it was rendered left a space which transalated into a margin-right:4px;

One fix is to apply a negative margin.